# migrate users for a site collection (not web app level)

Tags: migration

I did a 2010 to 2013 migration for a site collection. Is there a way to migrate users for a given site collection instead of web application? the following code is for web app. I dont want to touch the web app as its already running bunch of site collections. The 2013 farm is a fresh farm and not migrated from 2010.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -identity http://webapp
$wa.MigrateUsers($true)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that Site collection upgrade should convert the user name to claims friendly username (0#,w|domain\user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did my upgrade some site collection/s at the time, moving them in separate databases. I answered a similar question a year ago so i'm going to quote myself from that thread.

While the official way to do it provided by Microsoft is to [Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authenticatio](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985(v=office.15).aspx)n by converting a web application.

> "However, i was planning to move site collections in a temporerary
>   database, one at the time for several reasons. I searched and found this script
>   that simply converts a database from Classic to Claims. I've used it
>   for multiple databases and has not had one single error related to
>   authentication in 2013.
>
> The script is intended to be run AFTER the database has been mounted
>   to the web application. ( mount-spcontentdatabse ). This script must
>   be executed by your Farm account to. Check the source for the script
>   for more information, and be sure to test it before using it in
>   production if you decide to use it."

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://yourWebAppUrl 
$acc = 'domain\user' 
$arguments = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPMigrateUserParameters 
$arguments.AddDatabaseToMigrate($wa.ContentDatabases[1]) 
$wa.MigrateUsersToClaims($acc, $true, $arguments)
```

So, move a site collection from 2010 to its own temporary content database, move it a 2013 environment, mount it to a web application and then run the script. The important thing is that you have to target the script to the right database so if you have a new web application with one database and then attach a temporary content database, the database added order will be `$wa.ContentDatabases[1]`. If you have a web application with 3 databases and you mount a fourth database, the number should be `$wa.ContentDatabases[3]` as you start to count from 0.

I did this for all of our site collections in the spring -14 and we have not had any problems related to authentication after our migration.

[Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authentication in SharePoint 2013 the easy way](http://khalidansari.com/tag/classic-mode-authentication/)

Old thread: [web application is configured with claims authentication mode however the content database you are trying to attach is intended](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118457/web-application-is-configured-with-claims-authentication-mode-however-the-conten/118468#118468)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. But if you use Convert-SPWebApplication, it will only migrate the identities that have not been migrated yet.

Comment: A doubt here. Can't he write a small powershell script to get users  from user information list of that site collection and just import it into the other site collection?

Comment: I am migrating few sites at a time from 2010 to 2013. I was under the impression the site upgrade would convert the users from classic to claims. I hate to run ps command against web apps.

Comment: The conversion is done at the Web App level. There is no harm in running Convert-SPWebApplication multiple times.