# change authentication for one site collection

Tags: 2010, authentication

We migrated our production site collections to our test server like this:

prdserver/dev ---> testserver/dev (will be the new dev, the prd/dev will be deleted)
prdserver/prd ---> testserver/prd (will be used as uat)

This was done with a `Backup-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite` methods, with powershell.

I don't really know why, but the user names on the testserver/prd site collection look like `i:0#.w|domain\username`
The other 3 sites have no issues. After some research, I found that this is due to different authentication settings, but as far as I understood, this can only be done on application, and not on site collection level. Can someone help me what did here go wrong and how to repair it? I wanted to move my scripts from dev to uat, but all my access mgmt scripts are failing, because the domain\userid text is not recognized as valid userid. I do not want to build an extra hook in all the scripts, if it can be resolved otherwise.

Update:
Looks like that my initial finding was not correct. Both migrated sites have claims authentication, but the difference in the user names only comes visible, when a new user is added to the site. Existing users still show up in domain/username format.

Answer (score 0):

as you said, it is authentication configuration issue. Looks like in one farm you have classic authentication configured and other farm you have claims based authentication.

You cannot change the authentication on site level as it is Web application level configuration. I think you have to configured your dev/Uat with the same configuration as your production.

Comment: How is it then possible that on the testserver/dev  I see normal user names, and on testserver/prd not? They are both on the same web application.

Comment: what you mean bu testserver/dev & /prod? are these two site collections in single webapplication called testserver? do you have user profile service configured?

Comment: yes, they are two site collections under a single web application. User profile service is configured.

Comment: try to run the full sync of the user profile service and then check it.

Comment: Full sync complete, no improvement. The two site collections show the usernames in two different formats.

Comment: Where u seeing this? I mean on permission page or upper right hand corner where user name displayed?

Comment: On the permission page. Also,  if I try to set authorisations with PS like  `$user = Get-SPUser -Identity $userid -Web $site.RootWeb` the standard `Domain\userid` format leads to exception ("You must specify a valid user object or user identity."), while the `i:0#.w|Domain\username` format works.

Comment: that is normal, when you have claims based authentication enabled on web application level. If you dont want this then you have to create the classic web application

Comment: I understand this, my problem is that the two site collections are under the same application, still using different authentication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59741/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-vilmarci).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, the Authentication migration involves steps as follow

1. Convert your web application from classic to claims.
2. Convert your users to support claims authentication. In this step, the script will convert user identities from `domain\loginname` to `i:0#w|domain\loginname` in site collection user information list.

I thinking running step 2 multiple time won`t harm to the existing users. This was tested on our stage farm during migration.

But you can try this on your test farm with below steps

1. Create a test web application with classic authentication in the test server.
2. Convert your application to claim authentication. [steps here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154768/migrate-users-for-a-site-collection-not-web-app-level)
3. Restore your site collection which is in claims mode.
4. Run the users' migration script.
5. Verify your users using rest api call `siteurl/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('User Information List')/Items`. All users should be with `i:0#`

This is very safe before you run this on Prod server.

You can refer below post for the additional answer.

[migrate users for a site collection (not web app level)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154768/migrate-users-for-a-site-collection-not-web-app-level)

Comment: _All users should be with i:0#_ : But I don't want this. I would like the normal domain\username format, without the i:0#.

Comment: Can you run this query `siteurl/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('User Information List')/Items` on one of site collection and see how users are stored. You will see in the same format after users migration

Comment: I get error 404 :(

Comment: Did you replace `siteurl` with your site collection url?

Comment: I queried the User Information List otherwise. The list shows the usernames in the i:0#|domain\userid format.

Comment: I have tested our multiple production farms. The users Name (LoginName) value will be converted to `i:0#.w|domain\userid`.  This is valid format for claims Authentication provider web applications. I need to think why it is not appending `.w` and still working.

Comment: My typo. It is, as you mention `i:0#.w|domain\userid` however, only for one of the site collections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59746/discussion-between-venkat-konjeti-and-vilmarci).