# migrate users for a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration

Sorry for creating a new thread but I can't add a comment to the original thread [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154768/migrate-users-for-a-site-collection-not-web-app-level/154775#154775).

Just wanna know if it's possible to use UPN instead of SAM account (domain\user)? I.e:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://yourWebAppUrl 
$acc = 'UPN'
```

Our users login via email (UPN) + password, rather than using domain\user.

Here's what I've got:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://yourWebAppURL
$acc = "domain\farm admin"
$arguments = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPMigrateUserParameters

$arguments.AddDatabaseToMigrate($wa.ContentDatabases[4])
$wa.MigrateUsersToClaims($acc, $false, $arguments)
```

I've made sure that my database is in index 4. Checked by running $arguments or just running `$wa.contentdatabases`.

Well, I still couldn't login with my account. I could however login with my site collection admin which have setup on the SharePoint site.

Comment: What authentication method u are using? What's the reason for user migration?

Comment: I'm using claims authentication. I'm not migrating users, i'm migrating a site collection from 2010 (which uses classic authentication) to 2013 (claims).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your users are authenticating via Windows auth (classic or claims), they can use any valid format, including UPN.